# Initial animation on react-spring not working

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I'm using react-spring to animate the transition of opening and closing an accordion component that reveals some text. Using [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/pmndrs/react-spring/tree/master/demo/src/sandboxes/tree?file=/src/App.tsx) example on the documentation I was able to come up with a simpler version that creates a transition for the height and opacity:

```
function CollapseListItem({ title, text }: CollapseItemType) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [ref, { height: viewHeight }] = useMeasure();

  const { height, opacity } = useSpring({
    from: { height: 0, opacity: 0 },
    to: {
      height: isOpen ? viewHeight : 0,
      opacity: isOpen ? 1 : 0
    }
  });

  const toggleOpen = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={toggleOpen}>
        {title} click to {isOpen ? "close" : "open"}
      </button>
      <animated.div
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          opacity,
          height: isOpen ? "auto" : height,
          overflow: "hidden"
        }}
      >
        {text}
      </animated.div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The issue is that the height transition is only being shown when you close the accordion, when you open the accordion the text suddenly appears, but on the code I can't seem to find why it only works on close, I've tried to hardcode some `viewHeight` values but I've had no luck.

[Here's a code sandbox of what I have](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-boyd-wrkhr?file=/src/CollapseList.tsx:266-1001)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking more examples, I realized that I was putting the `ref` on the wrong component, this change solve the issue:

```
function CollapseListItem({ title, text }: CollapseItemType) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [ref, { height: viewHeight }] = useMeasure();

  const props = useSpring({
    height: isOpen ? viewHeight : 0,
    opacity: isOpen ? 1 : 0
  });

  const toggleOpen = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={toggleOpen}>
        {title} click to {isOpen ? "close" : "open"}
      </button>
      <animated.div
        style={{
          ...props,
          overflow: "hidden"
        }}
      >
        <div ref={ref}>{text}</div>
      </animated.div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[Here's the full solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-boyd-wrkhr?file=/src/CollapseList.tsx:255-880) in case anyone is also trying to build an animated accordion / collapse using spring.